The script tried to call a method on an incomplete object. error on production but not on localhost
I'm working on a laravel 10 project and I have several class to deal emails.
Recently I added some new email notifications.
I factorized my code for notification into a service :
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Request;
use App\Mail\CommentMail;
use App\Mail\InvitationMail;
use App\Mail\NewRequestMail;
use App\Mail\AffectationMail;
use App\Mail\FinishedRequestMail;
use App\Mail\ApplicantAffectationMail;
use App\Megaphone\NewComment;
use App\Megaphone\NewRequest;
use App\Megaphone\NewInvitation;
use App\Megaphone\NewAffectation;
use App\Megaphone\FinishedRequest;
use App\Megaphone\ApplicantAffectation;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class NotificationService
{
    /**
     * Sending notifications for new request.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  bool $manager
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendNewRequestNotification(User $user, Request $request, $manager = false) : void
    {
        $notification = new NewRequest(
            'Nouvelle demande',
            $request->user->name . ' a créé une nouvelle demande : "' . $request->title . '".',
            route('show', ['id' => $request->id]),
        );

        $this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification);

        // Manager case => verify the right preference between isManagerEmailEnabled() and isMailEnabled().
        if($manager) {
            if($user->isManagerEmailEnabled()) {
                $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification);
            }
        } else {
            if($user->isMailEnabled()) {
                $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification);
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Sending notifications for new comment.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  Comment $comment
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendCommentNotification(User $user, Request $request, Comment $comment) : void
    {
        $notification = new NewComment(
            'Nouveau commentaire',
            $comment->user->name . ' a laissé un nouveau commentaire à la demande "' . $request->title .'."',
            route('show', ['id' => $request->id]),
        );

        $this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification);

        if($user->isMailEnabled()) {
            $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification, $comment);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Sending notifications for new affectation.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendAffectationNotification(User $user, Request $request) : void
    {
        $notification = new NewAffectation(
            'Nouvelle affectation',
            'Vous avez reçu une nouvelle affectation pour la demande : "' . $request->title . '".',
            route('show', ['id' => $request->id]),
        );

        $this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification);

        if($user->isMailEnabled()) {
            $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Sending notifications for new invitation.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  string $senderName
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendInvitationNotification(User $user, Request $request, $senderName) : void
    {
        $notification = new NewInvitation(
            'Nouvelle invitation',
            $senderName . ' vous a envoyé une invitation à suivre la demande : "' . $request->title . '".',
            route('show', ['id' => $request->id]),
        );

        $this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification);

        if($user->isMailEnabled()) {
            $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification, null, $senderName);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Sending notifications for finished request.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendFinishedRequestNotification(User $user, Request $request) : void
    {
        $notification = new FinishedRequest(
            'Demande terminée',
            'La demande : "' . $request->title . '" est terminée.',
            route('show', ['id' => $request->id]),
        );

        $this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification);

        if($user->isMailEnabled()) {
            $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification);
        }
    }
        
    /**
     * Sending notifications for applicant affectation.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  mixed $senderName
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendApplicantAffectationNotification(User $user, Request $request, $senderName) : void
    {
        $notification = new ApplicantAffectation(
            'Demande créée en votre nom',
            $senderName . ' a créé la demande ' . $request->title . ' en votre nom.',
            route('show', ['id' => $request->id]),
        );

        $this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification);

        if($user->isMailEnabled()) {
            $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification, null, $senderName);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Sending a Megaphone application notification.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  mixed $notification
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendMegaphoneNotification(User $user, $notification) : void
    {
        $user->notify($notification);
    }

    /**
     * Sending an email notification.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @param  mixed $notification
     * @param  Comment $comment
     * @param  string $senderName
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendEmailNotification(User $user, Request $request, $notification, $comment = null, $senderName = null) : void
    {
        $notifUuid = $user->notifications()->latest()->first()->id;
        
        $toEmail = $user->isInfoManager() ? config('mail.info_notification_email') : $user->email;

        if($notification instanceof NewRequest) {
            Mail::to($toEmail)->queue(new NewRequestMail($request, $notifUuid));
        } elseif ($notification instanceof NewComment) {
            Mail::to($toEmail)->queue(new CommentMail($request, $comment, $notifUuid));
        } elseif ($notification instanceof NewAffectation) {
            Mail::to($toEmail)->queue(new AffectationMail($request, $notifUuid));
        } elseif ($notification instanceof NewInvitation) {
            Mail::to($toEmail)->queue(new InvitationMail($request, $senderName, $notifUuid));
        } elseif ($notification instanceof FinishedRequest) {
            Mail::to($toEmail)->queue(new FinishedRequestMail($request, $notifUuid));
        } elseif ($notification instanceof ApplicantAffectation) {
            Mail::to($toEmail)->queue(new ApplicantAffectationMail($request, $senderName, $notifUuid));
        }
    }
}



It allows me to use it like this on controllers or livewire components :

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notificationService = new NotificationService();
    }
[...]
       $this->notificationService->sendFinishedRequestNotification($this->req->user, $this->req);
[...]

It works fine on localhost (php artisan serve).
But when I deploy it on my local server (aka production), it throw me this error :
The script tried to call a method on an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "App\Mail\FinishedRequestMail" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded _before_ unserialize() gets called or provide an autoloader to load the class definition

Megaphone notifications works fine but not email notifications.
So it seems that in :
/**
     * Sending notifications for finished request.
     *
     * @param  User $user
     * @param  Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendFinishedRequestNotification(User $user, Request $request) : void
    {
        $notification = new FinishedRequest(
            'Demande terminée',
            'La demande : "' . $request->title . '" est terminée.',
            route('show', ['id' => $request->id]),
        );

        $this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification);

        if($user->isMailEnabled()) {
            $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification);
        }
    }


$this->sendMegaphoneNotification($user, $notification); works but not $this->sendEmailNotification($user, $request, $notification);
On my production server I'm using supervisor to deal email queues.
I can't reproduce the bug on localhost.
Does someone have an idea?

I suspect it has to do with Eager Loading handling configurations.
Check your log files for chatter about eager loading "warnings" (in local) / "errors" (in production).
Defaults differ between local and production -- options ranging from quietly allowing implied eager loading to throwing warnings and errors.
I've seen users configuring eager loading handling in the App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
